# apache2 Invalid command 'SSLEngine'

Tags: ssl, apache-httpd

When I restart httpd, I get the following error.  What am I missing?

```
[root@localhost ~]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 22 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/sites.conf:
Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I have installed mod_ssl using `yum install mod_ssl openssh`

```
Package 1:mod_ssl-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package openssh-5.3p1-70.el6_2.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

My sites.conf looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerName shop.itmanx.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@itmanx.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog logs/shop-error.log
    CustomLog logs/shop-access.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName secure.itmanx.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@itmanx.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/secure.itmanx.com/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/secure.itmanx.com/server.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/secure.itmanx.com/chain.crt

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog logs/shop-ssl-error.log
    CustomLog logs/shop-ssl-access.log    
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Probably you do not load the ssl module. You should have a *LoadModule* directive somewhere in your apache configuration files.

Something like:

```
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_ssl.so
```

Usually apache configuration template has (on any distribution) a file called (something like) `loadmodule.conf` in which you should find a `LoadModule` directive for each module you load into apache at server start.

Comment: Also, it's necessary to install `mod_ssl`. On RHEL and CentOS, this is done with `yum install mod_ssl`.

Comment: For Apache 2.4 it is yum install mod24_ssl

Comment: `sudo a2enmod ssl`

Comment: @AlejandroPabloTkachuk there is No package mod24_ssl available. For me just `yum install mod_ssl` worked perfectly.

Comment: @vijay the name of the package and how to enable it is _distribution dependent_. In addition, the package name can change in time.

Comment: What's the advantage of having both http and https ? We have really to duplicate the virtual records twice just to change *:80 to *:443 lines?
How to cause the browser to switch automatically to httpS when typing mydomain.com on the address bar?

Answer (score 179):

On many systems (Ubuntu, Suse, Debian, ...) run the following command to enable Apache's SSL mod:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

[a2enmod man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apache2/a2enmod.8.en.html)

Comment: This is Debian-specific but the question is not tagged Debian.

Comment: is a2enmod really Debian specific?  Or are you complaining about the use of sudo?

Comment: `a2enmod` is Debian specific. It manages symlinks for the way Debian splits apache configurations. Your command is the equivalent of `ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-{available,enabled}/ssl.load; ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-{available,enabled}/ssl.conf`

Comment: `a2enmod` is also used on suse.

Comment: ..and on Ubuntu

Answer (score 31):

On CentOS 7 installing the package "mod_ssl" and restarting the apache server worked for me:

```
yum install mod_ssl
systemctl restart httpd
```

Comment: It's work for me on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 18):

httpd24 solution:

```
yum install mod24_ssl
```

Comment: That presumably works for (some) RPM-based distributions only. Which one? Why does it fix the problem?

Comment: Worked on Amazon Linux and Centos for me. It's specifically for Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubntu 18.04 bionic.

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: The second answer already recomends `sudo a2enmod ssl;` Maybe you should add a comment there to restart the server after the change.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error while installing the SSL Certificate on my website. I have fixed it by executing the following command in the terminal.

```
# yum install mod_ssl
# httpd -t
# systemctl restart httpd
```

I am sure that the above commands will fix your error.